# %do% Vs. %dopar%, %dopar% does not make any changes, no warnings

Tags: r, doparallel

(There's no tag for r-parallel-processing or R's foreach package, if there was I would have tagged those here. Tag suggestions welcome).

I have a data frame "training_data" and a vector "cats" (for categorical data).

cats looks like `c("fruits", "vegetables", "meats")`

I want to loop over each of cats within training data and replace any low frequency levels with just "Other".

This works:

```
library(foreach)
foreach(c = cats) %do% { # not parallel processing
  print(c)
  freqs <- table(training_data[c])
  low_freqs <- names(which(freqs < 20000))
  training_data[c][[1]] <- ifelse(training_data[c][[1]] %in% low_freqs, "Other", training_data[c][[1]])
  return(NULL) # otherwise spits out the whole thing
}
```

On each iteration, the first line print(c) outputs the value of the vector cats that's being operated on and I see it in the console:

"fruits"
"vegetables"
"meats"

After those cats, 3 instances of NULL are printed to the terminal, expected due to the last line in the loop. When I then check my data frame training_data, the categorical variables have been transformed as expected. Any level with frequency less than 20k has been replaced with other.

However, if I try to use parallel:

```
library(foreach)
foreach(c = cats) %dopar% { # parallel (I have 8 cores)
  print(c)
  freqs <- table(training_data[c])
  low_freqs <- names(which(freqs < 20000))
  training_data[c][[1]] <- ifelse(training_data[c][[1]] %in% low_freqs, "Other", training_data[c][[1]])
  #return(NULL) # otherwise spits out the whole thing
}
```

All that happens is the NULLS are printed tot he console. The training data is not transformed and there is no print(c) shown in the console.

Why does only %do% work and not %dopar%?

Comment: WIth %dopar% the  the assignment to training_data occurs within each created subprocess, which does not share a common environment, so the changes are discarded. With %do% the variable is in the current environment so the modified value remains.

Comment: Ah. I see that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach, using some different sample data. With parallel, the data of the iterator is  copied into the subprocess, so limiting what's copied is important for performance and memory usage.

```r
library(doParallel)

# make a cluster

cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)

# sample data

cats <- c("fruits", "vegetables", "meats")
df <- read.csv(text = "
cat,n
fruits,1
fruits,2
vegetables,4
meats,5
", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Use foreach to iterate over a split dataframe, so only the subset data
# will be copied into each parallel process. Specify .combine = rbind to
# bind the resulting dataframe into one dataframe parallel 

result <- foreach(dfs = split(df, df$cat), .combine = rbind) %dopar% {

 # Print to show the structure of each split - Won't print in parallel
 # because the output .. will go to the console output of each process


  cat("Inside...\n")
  print(dfs)

  # Derive a new column
  dfs$new_col <- ifelse(dfs$n > 2, ">2", "<=2")

  # Return the result without printing
  invisible(dfs)  
}

# Print the combined new dataframe
print(result)
#>          cat n new_col
#> 1     fruits 1     <=2
#> 2     fruits 2     <=2
#> 4      meats 5      >2
#> 3 vegetables 4      >2
```